# Failed to create field with CASE WHEN statement and aggregation

Tags: looker-studio

I have this calculated field in Google Data Studio:

[image]

***Field Name***: `new_users_android_minus`

***Formula***:

```
MAX(CASE
    WHEN is_new_user>=1 AND platform="ANDROID" THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END)
```

When I try to make a copy of this formula to a new field, or even when I try to update the existing field just adding a white space, I get this error:

> *Failed to create field. Please try again later.*

In other words, the report and the field are working perfectly, but I can't update the existing field or use this formula in a new field. I'm facing this behavior with many fields where I use `CASE WHEN` inside aggregations `MAX()` and `COUNT_DISTINCT()`. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Is this a bug in Google Data Studio, or am I missing something?